# Regex using positive look ahead not directly after

Tags: regex

I have product codes for example HX3923, which always start with 2 capital letters, and end with 4 numbers. Some products have "gold" color, which is somewhere in the text.

Example:

HX3923, width: 0.3, height: 0.7, gold, HX3924, color="blue", width=0.3

I need to match **HX3923**, but not **HX3924**, since the latter has no gold color.

**This selects both product codes**

```
[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d\d
```

I thought I needed to add something like

```
[?=gold)
```

But that looks directly after the product code. How can I make sure it looks if there is gold BEFORE the next product code "starts"?

Currently have this **ugly** solution:

```
[A-Z][A-Z]\d\d\d\d(?=.{0,100}gold)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current approach `(?=.{0,100}gold)` uses a positive lookahead to assert `gold` after 0 - 100 characters.

Instead, one option is to use a capturing group `()`, word boundaries `\b` and a [tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900794/tempered-greedy-token-what-is-different-about-placing-the-dot-before-the-negat) approach to match gold before encountering another `[A-Z][A-Z]\d{4}` pattern.

```
\b([A-Z][A-Z]\d{4})\b(?:(?![A-Z][A-Z]\d{4}).)*\bgold\b
```

In parts

- `\b([A-Z][A-Z]\d{4})\b` Match 2 uppercase chars and 4 digits in capturing **group 1**
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `(?!` Negative lookahead, assert what is on the right is not

    - `[A-Z][A-Z]\d{4}` Match 2 uppercase chars and 4 digits
  - `).` Close lookahead and match any char except a newline
- `)*` Close non capturing group and repeat 0+ times
- `\bgold\b` Match `gold` between word boundaries

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/VEWe1t/1)

The values are in group 1.